# asp.net gridview model binding to possible null entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, lazy-loading

I have a gridview in my ui that binds to the result of a BLL->DAL call as below:
UI

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    gvUserList.ItemType = POCO.User;
    gvUserList.DataSource = GetUsers();
    gvUserList.DataBind();
}
```

DAL

```
public static List<User> GetAllUsers()
{
   using (var dbContext = new MyEntities())
   {
       return dbContext.Users.Include("Manager").Include("Status").Include("Office").ToList();
   }
}
```

The lazy loading works perfectly, however I get the lazy loading error:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used
>   for operations that require a connection.

When, for example, a user does not have a manager or a user does not have a status in the database. Is there something that I need to do on the binding of the grid to handle null entities?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error occurs in code that I have not included, namely

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Manager">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblUserManager" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Manager.FullName") %>' NullDisplayText="None"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

After changing the Eval to Bind it worked.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Manager">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblUserManager" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Manager.FullName") %>' NullDisplayText="None"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Hope this helps someone else running into the same issue.